# Laravel 5.8 handling all erros in one view

Tags: laravel, error-handling

I am creating a all-in-one page for all errors in Laravl app. The error page should include a layout for currently logged in user: normal user, admin and guest. To be able to use `Auth::check()`, I created error page using fallback route.

```
Route::fallback(function () {
    return view('errors.general', ['msg'=>'Error Description']);
});
```

And the view:

```
@php
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->check())
        $layout = "layouts.admin";
    elseif (Auth::check())
        $layout = "layouts.app";
    else 
        $layout = "layouts.start";
@endphp

@extends($layout)

@section('content')
    <div class="error-container">
        <div class="error-box">
            <div class="error-text">
                {{ $msg }}
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

The structure is working for 404 errors. But as for 500 errors, Laravel is showing default 500 page. How to direct all errors to use the same view with additonal error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating fallback route, handle all exception inside a Error Handler : `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

And you can also check which user is logged in inside handler with below code it is just a basic example with which you can handle 500 errors like below code:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        // 404 page when a model is not found
        if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
                // Your custom view for admin
            } else {
                //Your custom view for another user
            }

        }
        if ($exception instanceof \ErrorException) {
            if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
                // Your custom view for admin
            } else {
                //Your custom view for another user
            }
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate for all kinds of exceptions?

Comment: Yes check above code again, You can define all kinds of exception you want to render there. As far as i know `\ErrorException` will catch all kinds of exception.

Answer (score 0):

The fallback route is only catches non-existent routes (i.e., 404):
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#fallback-routes

But you can define your own error pages.
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/errors#custom-http-error-pages

> Laravel makes it easy to display custom error pages for various HTTP status codes. For example, if you wish to customize the error page for 404 HTTP status codes, create a `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`.

In order to use your single error layout, you could do something like this:

**resources/views/errors/500.blade.php**

```php
@include('layouts.error',['msg' => $exception->getMessage()])
```

**EDIT:** However, I do not believe that error pages load the session middleware, so you will likely have trouble attempting to use the Auth facade without additional effort.

Comment: Yes, custom error pages `errors/500.blade.php` do not load session middleware by default so auth functions are not working.